# Connecting tables of two or more databases with each other in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, sqliteopenhelper

I just wanted to know if there is any way to connect two tables of two different databases under one project.
I have the databases as follow

First database

```
private String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE  "+ TABLE_USER + "(" +
        COLUMN_USER_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_USER_MOBILE + " TEXT," + 
        COLUMN_USER_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_USER_MOTHERNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_FATHERNAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_USER_CONFIRM_PASSWORD + " TEXT " + ")";
```

Second database

```
        private String CREATE_BABY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_BABY + "(" +
        COLUMN_BABY_ID + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " + COLUMN_BABY_NAME + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_BABY_DATE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_BABY_GENDER + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_BABY_AGE + 
          " TEXT " + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, application can has connect to different databases. (By clear sqlite or any db library, like Room)
But your question contains two tables but not two databases. You must just put them to one database.

Comment: These are the to tables of different databases which I want to connect

Comment: When it looks like OP might be confusing a concept, in this case Tables vs Databases, it is customary to post a comment first, asking for clarification, then based on the response you can write your killer solution that we can all vote for. Your assumption was wrong in this case, but it was reasonably ambiguous, so it was worth asking a question, and that is what comments are for. Try not to ask questions or postulate assumptions in the Answer (I still violate this all the time) we should ask for clarification first.

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution to this is to query each of the databases separately and then merge or join the results in your application logic.